# .toggle is not working properly in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

**In IE8 the toggle kinda works but it overlays the content below.** It works fine in all the other browsers. I've been trying for the past 2 hours to fix this but no luck...

[Here's what I mean](http://www.sopranowebdesign.com/static/test.html)

**jquery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    $('.toggle').hide();

    $('.expand-all').click(function(){
        // switch visibility
        $(this).data('is_visible', !$(this).data('is_visible'));

        // change the link depending on whether the element is shown or hidden
        $(this).html( (!$(this).data('is_visible')) ? 'Expand all' : 'Hide');

        $(this).next().toggle();

    return false;
    }); 


});
```

**html**:

```
    <div id="categories">
        <div class="cat">
            <h3>Rice</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Rice brand 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Rice brand 2</a></li>
                <li class="expand-all">Expand all</li>
                <div class="toggle">
                    <li><a href="">Rice brand 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Rice brand 1</a></li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="cat">etc</div>
        <div class="cat">etc</div>
        <div class="cat">etc</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The javascript console for that example page is indicating that jquery isn't being loaded. The url for your JS resource is 'tangola1.local'.

Comment: sorry about that, the jquery file was loaded locally. it should work in chrome/firefox now

Comment: Works fine for me in IE8.  Perhaps you should describe what problem you are seeing.

Comment: For me it works fine in IE8. It stops working when you enter quirks mode. And also IE7 will not work

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though you are having an issue with the `display : inline-block` property you are setting.

Here is something to try, for more things to try just Google "internet explorer 8 inline-block": http://www.compsoft.co.uk/Blog/2009/11/inline-block-not-quite-inline-blocking.html

Also IE7 will not accept the `display : inline-block` property, so you need to add this to your code to make it work in IE7 as well:

```
.some-ele {
    display  : inline-block;
    *display : inline;
    zoom     : 1;
}
```

The `*display` property is invalid but will still be read by IE7 and for it to take affect the element must have the `hasLayout` property which you can't set manually but you can force it to be set by setting `zoom : 1`.

For IE6 you need to specify a height for `display : inline-block` to work but if you only want to specify a height for IE6 you can use `_height : XXpx` which will only be read by IE6 (more invalid code that IE will digest). Here is some info on this: http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Comment: sorry about that, the jquery file was loaded locally. it should work in chrome/firefox now. The IE8 still doesn't work.

Comment: In IE8 the toggles work, but they sometimes overlay the content below. Is that what you mean to fix?

Comment: I'm not sure why the layout isn't being updated when you click the expand links but I added a little bit about backwards compatibility for `display : inline-block` that you might find useful.